# Заголовок <format> не находится, хотя версия C++20 в VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Код для проверки версии C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << __cplusplus << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

В моём случае выходные данные:

```
202002
```

Это и есть версия C++20. Вот мой `tasks.json` файл:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-std=c++20",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json` файл:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++20",
            "cStandard": "gnu23",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Версия VS code: **1.83.1**

Версия extension для C++: **1.17.5**

Версия компилятора: **gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0**

Все настройки для изменения стандарта  C++ были изменены на с++20

Однако библиотеки по типу `<bit>, <compare>, <ranges>`, которые как раз и появились в C++20 работают. Помогите мне исправить эту проблему, чтобы  появился в списке head's

Comment: ¿Какая версия компилятора? В gcc енто долго допиливали (и еще, кажется, продолжают).

Comment: @user7860670, можете пояснить, как это узнать?

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc --version`

Comment: @user7860670, 
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

Comment: А нужен 13, как минимум. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20